# pandas merge df based of 2 column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 df. the first one is list of id and for each id there list of days 01-01-2013 until 12-31-2013 . I have 30 unique id for example, df1:

```
id    date
1      01-01-2013
1      01-02-2013
1      01-03-2013
....
1      12-31-2013
2      01-01-2013
2      01-02-2013
....
2      12-31-2013
```

my second df is  id, sub_ id (each sub_id contain to some id )dates of diagnosis and label for disease- 0 or 1. for example:

```
id   sub_id      date    disease
1     345      01-01-2013         0
1     967       01-01-2013        1
2      843     06-03-2013        0
```

and so on. I want to merge the df base on id and date. so I will get consecutive days of all days in the year for each id with label of disease. I don't care about the sub_id, HOWEVER if I have 2 same dates, and I have at least 1 sick sub_id I want to return label of 1 in that day. and if there is no value, fill  nan with 0
for example: df2

```
id    date          disease
1      01-01-2013     1
1       01-02-2013    0
1        01-13-2013    0
.....
```

I have tried this code:

```
df2.sort_values('disease').drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='last').merge(df1,on=['id','date'],how='right')
```

but some id with label 1 its results label of 0
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `groupby`:

```
df2.groupby(['id','date']).max().reset_index().merge(df1,on=['id','date'],how='right')
```